# Convert an unsigned integer back to char*?

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

I have a hash function which returns back to me an unsigned integer `uint32_t` given a `char*` as shown below:

```
uint32_t key_hashing(const char* key)
{
    return hashing(key, 0x7fffffff, 101);
}

uint32_t hashing(const char* word, int tsize, uint32_t seed)
{
    char c;
    uint32_t h = seed;
    for ( ; (c=*word) != '\0'; ++word)
    {
        h ^= ( (h<<5) + c + (h >> 2) );
    }
    return ((uint32_t)(h&0x7fffffff) % tsize);
}
```

Now I want to do opposite: Let's say I have been given `uint32_t` number, I want to revert back to its original form which was in `char*` earlier. How can I do that? Basically my `uint32_t` number should give me back the original char* that was passed.

Comment: Hash algorithms are one way.  You cannot reverse the hash to produce the original `char*`. The only option is to use brute force - run every possible `char*` value through the algorithm until you find values that produce the same hash.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the concept of hashing...

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912220/crc16-to-string

Comment: I'm flagging as Too Broad because it requires discovering how to solve an NP-hard problem efficiently.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: this isn't NP hard. An NP hard problem *has* a definitive, unambiguous answer. This has an unbounded set of possible answers. You'd have to add further constraints (e.g., that the input consisted of no more than N words, with no punctuation, from a specified word list) to narrow it down to a single possible answer.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I suppose you're correct. Serves me right for tossing that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not going to work because of hashing collisions: there are arbitrary many permutations of byte arrays possible but only a fixed number of distinct `uint32_t`, hence a bunch of different `char *` are going to hash to the *same* `uint32_t` value.